# How to see average game length for specific chess opening (number of moves)?

Tags: opening, statistics, game-length

How to see average game lenght for specific chess opening?

Is there some chess database which allow me to see specific opening game length?

For example:

- Sicilian defense (average length is: 80.5)
- Caro-Kann defense (average length is: 60.7)

I want to learn which opening lead to short, medium, long game.

It is easy to find white/black/draw statistics but hard to find length of games.

Answer (score 1):

Chessbase has a function "Opening Report" which gives average lenght of White wins/Black wins/draws
Just setup che base position on the chessboard and right-click it